# Cleaning Range Ventilation

Tags: equipment, cleaning

I have a hood ventilation system that vents to the outside.  It has removable grease traps, as pictured below.  I've put them in the dishwasher, but the grease has polymerized onto them.  I'm looking for cleaning tips.
[image]

Comment: @ChingChong - possibly, but it is tough to get in the crevices with barkeeper friend.  In the end, that may be the only solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you do it on the steam setting? If you have one? I feel like when I see them washing them in restaurants, they use high-pressure steam/water cleaning to get them cleaned off.

Comment: I have never used Barkeeper's Friend but scouring agents. I would try to get in the crevices with a toothbrush (and have much patience).